# Pre-filled create form in admin class

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I have two entities `Crawler` and `Customer`. `Crawler` contains entries parsed from a remote URL, `Customer` contains manually created entries from the `Crawler` data.

I created a `CrawlerAdmin` and a `CustomerAdmin`, respectively. Now, for creating a new `Customer` entry I wish for a custom action in the `CrawlerAdmin` list views, like "Create Customer". By clicking the button, the `CustomerAdmin` create view should be displayed with the fields pre-filled with the value of the selected `Crawler` entry.

**How can I produce this kind of result?**

Edit:
As a possible alternative, I created a "clone" function in a custom CRUDController. It takes the `Crawler` entry and automatically creates a new `Customer` entry based on it. It would then just be necessary to redirect to edit view of the newly created `Customer` entry.

**How would I redirect from the custom Contoller to `CustomerAdmin` edit view with the ID of the newly created entry?**

This is the controller:

```
<?php
// src/CrawlerBundle/Controller/CRUDController.php

namespace CrawlerBundle\Controller;

use FrontendBundle\Entity\Customer;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Controller\CRUDController as Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;

class CRUDController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @param $id
     * @return RedirectResponse
     */
    public function cloneAction($id)
    {
        $object = $this->admin->getSubject();

        if (!$object) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException'unable to find object');
        }

        $newObject = new Customer();
        $newObject->setCompanyName($object->getCompanyName().' (Clone)');
        $newObject->setRegisterNumber($object->getRegisterNumber().' (Clone)');
        $newObject->setFields(array()); // ignore this

        $this->admin->create($newObject);

        $this->addFlash('sonata_flash_success', 'Cloned successfully');

        // return new RedirectResponse($this->admin->generateUrl('list'));

        // if you have a filtered list and want to keep your filters after the redirect
        return new RedirectResponse($this->admin->generateUrl('list', array('filter' => $this->admin->getFilterParameters())));
        // just redirects to the class list view
    }
}
```

My service definition:

```
crawler.admin.crawler:
    class: CrawlerBundle\Admin\CrawlerAdmin
    arguments: [~, CrawlerBundle\Entity\Crawler, CrawlerBundle:CRUD]
    tags:
         - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: admin, label: Crawler, pager_type: "simple" }
```

If you need more info, please comment.

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: You can set an url parameter to your create link, and get it in the configureFormFields function of your admin in order to set the getSubject() with it.

Comment: Yes, linked to the current Admin, not a different one :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, In your link to create a new child, just pass an url parameter with the parent id, after, in your Child Admin, just get this parameter and set the new object with. Exemple :  the configureFormFields function :

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $object = $formMapper->getFormBuilder()->getData();
    $parentId = $this->getRequest()->get('objectId');

    if (null === $object || null === $object->getParentDocument()) {
        $object = new ChildEntity();
        $parentDoc = $this->getParentAdmin()->getObject($parentId);
        if (null !== $parentDoc) {
            $object->setParentDocument($parentDoc);
        }
        $formMapper->getFormBuilder()->setData($object);
    }

    ....
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this is for Symfony 3?

Comment: I'm giving it a try. Thanks for the answer.